# Oauth Facebook Issue with redirect URI

Tags: plugin-duktoauth

I am getting an error with oauth (1.0.79) when using Facebook:

> Required option not passed: access_token Array (
>   [{"error":{"message":"Error_validating_verification_code__Please_make_sure_your_redirect_uri_is_identical_to_the_one_you_used_in_the_OAuth_dialog_request","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"A2ThFvRVsAZ"}}]
>   => )

Facebook is changing the url entered and replacing the /'s in the p=actions/oauth/connect part of the redirect URI with ASCII characters %2F p=actions%2Foauth%2Fconnect which I assume is then not matching the 2 uri's causing the above error.

Is this the issue? Is there a workaround? Or is this a tweak that needs to be made to oauth?

Cheers

Comment: You are correct that it is an encoding error. I have reported it to Dukt here: https://github.com/dukt/craft-oauth/issues/18. In the mean time, you can modify oauth/providers/Facebook.php and just hardcode the redirectUrl with the last two forward-slashes replaced with %2F.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `usePathInfo = true` in your Craft general settings to force Craft to use PATH_INFO to generate URLs.

https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#usePathInfo

Dukt OAuth should now show you a redirect URI without a query string (Facebook doesn’t like slashes in the query string and automatically encodes them) and you should be able to make the URIs match exactly.